# Wait all async function inside map to finish execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-redux

I want to finish the execution of **ALL** async functions inside a map, and then change state of my component.  I leave you a reduced part of the code in case you can help me.

Just all I am trying to do is to show my own Permissions screen every time the user cancel it.

To simplify, I have this:

```
const permissions = {
    cameraRoll: {
        iconType: "ionicon",
        iconName: "ios-images",
        title: "Enable camera roll",
        subtitle:
          "To upload content from your Gallery, you have to granted the camera roll permission",
        buttonText: "Enable camera roll",
        checkPermission: checkCameraRollPermission,
        requirePermission: requireCameraRollPermission,
      },
    };
}


const checkCameraRollPermission = async () => {
    const { status, canAskAgain } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
    );
    return { status, canAskAgain };
  };


  const requireCameraRollPermission = async () => {
    const { status, canAskAgain } = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
    );
    return { status, canAskAgain };
  };


/* I HAVE TO WAIT FOR ALL THE FUNCTIONS TO FINISH EXECUTION
FOR EACH OBJECT ON THE MAP BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING :( */
getMissingPermissions = () => {
    // Only check permissions on the foreground
    if (AppState.currentState.match(/active/)) {
      // We have to empty the current missing permssions and recalculate them
      const permissionsArray = [];
      Promise.all(
        Object.keys(permissions).map((key) => {
          permissions[key].checkPermission().then(({ status }) => {
            if (status !== "granted") {
              permissionsArray.push(permissions[key]);
            }
          });
        })
      ).then(() => {

        this.setState({
          missingPermissions: permissionsArray,
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The callback for `.map()` is supposed to `return` a value

Comment: Right now your `permissions` object has only one requested permission. Will it eventually have more than one? If not, then you don't even need to map the permissions calls.

Comment: yeah it has more, it is simplified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Promise.all` you need to provide promises as an array. At present you are not returning anything from within the map which is what is causing the problem.

Also instead of using a permissionsArray variable you can simply return the required value from within nested promise and that will be available in the `Promise.all(...).then(...)` response

```
getMissingPermissions = () => {
    // Only check permissions on the foreground
    if (AppState.currentState.match(/active/)) {
      // We have to empty the current missing permssions and recalculate them
      Promise.all(
        Object.keys(permissions).map((key) => {
          return permissions[key].checkPermission().then(({ status }) => {
            if (status !== "granted") {
              return permissions[key];
            }
            return;
          });
        })
      ).then((res) => {
        const permissionsArray = res.filter(Boolean)// Filter out undefined values
        this.setState({
          missingPermissions: permissionsArray,
        });
      });
    }
  };
```